# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64,) for Tensor 'targets/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 3)'

Tags: python, tensorflow

i'm working on a project where my goal is to identify what kind of illness this person have. I've 3 kind of image the ones named virus.numer, bacteria.numer, normal.numer (exemple: normal.133)

it work but after some step i get this error and i don't know how to resolve this problem

```
train_data = create_train_data()
test_data = process_test_data()
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression


convnet = input_data(shape=[None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1], name='input')

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 128, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 1024, activation='relu')
convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 3, activation='softmax')
convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')

model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, tensorboard_dir='log')

if os.path.exists('{}.meta'.format(MODEL_NAME)):
    model.load(MODEL_NAME)
    print('model loaded!')

train = train_data
test = test_data

X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
Y = [i[1] for i in train]

test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
test_y = [i[1] for i in test]

model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=6, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}), 
    snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
```

Comment: easy way to find the error is by printing all the shapes of tensor in every line. I think your input shape should be (img_size, img_size, 1)

Comment: how can i print all the shapes?

Comment: what is the shape of train data and test data?